# Как настроить сглаживание в случае использования system.drawing.printing?

Tags: c#, print

Имеется принтер Intermec PC43d, в свойствах его печати есть вкладка Графика с параметрами Сглаживания (Полутон, Упорядоченное, Алгебраическое). Проблема возникает при печати из приложения с использованием drawing.printing:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += (object printSender, PrintPageEventArgs printE) =>
{
   var image = ByteArrayToImage(_imageBytes);
   printE.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(image, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
};
pd.Print();
```

Независимо от того какое сглаживание поставить в свойствах принтера, будет стабильно печататься со сглаживанием Полутон (в итоге очень некачественная картинка).

Как это исправить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настройки сглаживания применяются к линиям, а не к картинкам. Для картинок это называется "интерполяция".

Установить режим интерполяции можно через `printE.Graphics.InterpolationMode`